# Maze BFS in Python

Tags: python, beginner, python-3.x

The program below was made for a game named CheckIO, and it works. I'm just wondering if there is any way to make the code more readable.

edit: hi luke15g

```
def checkio(maze_map):
    #the walls of the maze are already surrounded by 1's
    start_x,start_y=1,1
    stop_x,stop_y=10,10
    class Point:
        directions={'N':(-1,0),'W':(0,-1),'E':(0,1),'S':(1,0)}
        def __init__(self,other=None,direction=None):
            if other!=None:
                self.road=other.road+direction
                self.x=other.x+Point.directions[direction][0]
                self.y=other.y+Point.directions[direction][1]
            else:
                self.x,self.y=None,None
                self.road=''
        def hit(self):
            return maze_map[self.x][self.y]==1
        def new_point(self):
            for char in Point.directions:
                x=Point(self,char)
                if not x.hit():
                    yield x
        def found_it(self):
            return self.x==stop_x and self.y==stop_y
    p=[Point()]
    p[0].x,p[0].y=start_x,start_y
    begin=0
    maze_map[start_x][start_y]=1
    while begin<=len(p)-1:
        if p[begin].found_it():
            return p[begin].road
        x=p[begin].new_point()
        while 1:
            try:
                new=next(x)
            except StopIteration:
                break
            p.append(new)
            maze_map[new.x][new.y]=1
        begin+=1
```

Comment: Is this in Python 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: It's version 3.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In terms of readability:

- There is no reason to nest the class inside the function (your current need to do so is caused by bad design, see below); doing so just distracts the reader from the actual business of the function.
- Both function and class (and the class's methods) should have [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) explaining what they do.
- Python has a `bool` type, so `while 1:` is generally written `while True:`.
- You *mostly* follow [the style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), but a bit more whitespace (e.g. around methods, assignments) would be helpful.

---

On `Point` itself:

- `directions` is a constant, so should be `UPPERCASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES` to indicate as much: `DIRECTIONS`.
- It seems odd to take an `other` `Point` instance to `__init__`. This is particularly awkward when you have `p = [Point()]; p[0].x, p[0].y = start_x, start_y` - contrast with `[Point(start_x, start_y)]`. Move the functionality for creating a `Point` from an existing instance into a `@classmethod`, so you would call `x = Point.from_point(self, char)`.
- `road`, the path of directions taken to get to the current point, could be a `list` instead of a `str`.
- Rather than `found_it`, refactor to `is_at(self, x, y)`, so you don't have to have `stop_x` and `stop_y` in scope (see above) and `if p[begin].found_it():` becomes `if p[begin].is_at(stop_x, stop_y):`, which is a little more explicit.
- Similarly, `hit` and `new_point` should take the `maze_map` as a parameter, rather than relying on scope.
- `hit` is only called within the class, so should probably be private-by-convention (i.e. named `_hit` instead).
- `Point.directions` is also accessible via `self.directions`, which will handle inheritance better.
- `new_point` yields more than one `Point`, so should be plural (`new_points`).

With these modifications:

```
class Point:

    DIRECTIONS = {'N': (-1, 0), 'W': (0, -1), 'E': (0, 1), 'S': (1, 0)}

    def __init__(self, x, y, road=None):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
        self.road = road or []

    @classmethod
    def from_point(cls, other, direction):
        """Create a new point from an existing point and direction."""
        d_x, d_y = cls.DIRECTIONS[direction]
        return cls(
            other.x + d_x, 
            other.y + d_y, 
            other.road + [direction],
        )

    def _hit(self, map):
        """Would this point hit a wall in the map?"""
        return map[self.x][self.y] == 1

    def new_points(self, map):
        """Generate new points from the current point."""
        for char in self.directions:
            new_point = Point.from_point(self, char)
            if not new_point._hit(map):
                yield new_point

    def is_at(self, x, y):
        """Whether the point is at the specified location."""
        return self.x == x and self.y == y
```

---

And on the `checkio` function:

- You can neaten `while begin <= len(p) - 1:` to `while begin < len(p):`.
- The names are pretty bad - `p` should be `points`, `begin` should be `current` (it's only `begin` at the beginning!).
- The `while 1:` loop would be much neater if you just iterated over `new_points`: `for point in points[current].new_points():`.

As modified:

```
def checkio(maze_map):
    """Solve the maze.

    The walls of the maze are already surrounded by 1s.

    """
    start_x, start_y = 1, 1
    stop_x, stop_y = 10, 10
    points = [Point(start_x, start_y)]
    current = 0
    maze_map[start_x][start_y] = 1
    while current < len(points):
        if points[current].is_at(stop_x, stop_y):
            return ''.join(points[current].road)
        for new_point in points[current].new_points(maze_map):
            points.append(new_point)
            maze_map[new_point.x][new_point.y] = 1
        current += 1
```

---

If you implemented `__eq__` and `__hash__` on the `Point` class, you could keep a `set` of the points you've already visited, rather than adding a *"wall"* into the map when you visit a particular location.

Comment: What does @classmethod do?

Comment: @user2015213 it makes a method act on *the class*, instead of *an instance*, see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12179271/3001761, http://stackoverflow.com/q/136097/3001761

Answer (score 2):

### Point

It would help a lot if `Point` did not have to know about how to read the maze.  Instead, it should concentrate on being a coordinate and crumbtrail.  The `hit()` and `found_it()` functionality should move into a `Maze` class.

The fact that you wrote `start_x,start_y` and `stop_x,stop_y` indicates that `Point` is not doing its job — it should be more like `start = Point(1, 1)`.  `p=[Point()]; p[0].x,p[0].y=start_x,start_y` is even weirder — it should be `queue = [start]`.  The `0` in `self.x=other.x+Point.directions[direction][0]` is also rather mysterious.  The remedy for all of these problems is to make `Point` into a `namedtuple`.

According to your `directions`, the +x axis points south, and the +y axis points east.  It would be more conventional to rename x and y as "row" and "column".

### Maze

Now that we have a `Point`, it would be helpful have a way to fetch and set the value at a `Point`.  For that, we define a `Maze` class, with an overridden `[]` operator.

With all the clutter out of the way, what remains is a `solve()` method that processes the queue.  I suggest renaming `p` to `queue` and using idiomatic iteration techniques.

### Suggested solution

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Point(namedtuple('Point', ['r', 'c'])):
    def __init__(self, r, c):
        self.src = None

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Point(self.r + other.r, self.c + other.c)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        return self + -other

    def __neg__(self):
        return Point(-self.r, -self.c)

    @property
    def neighbors(self):
        for delta in Point.DIRECTIONS:
            p = self + delta
            p.src = self
            yield p

    @property
    def path(self):
        if self.src is not None:
            yield from self.src.path
            yield Point.DIRECTIONS[self - self.src]

Point.DIRECTIONS = {
                        Point(-1, 0): 'N',
        Point(0, -1): 'W',              Point(0, +1): 'E',
                        Point(+1, 0): 'S',
}

class Maze:
    def __init__(self, maze_map):
        """maze_map is a two-dimensional array, where each 1 indicates an
           obstacle.  The walls of the maze must be surrounded by 1's."""
        self.maze_map = [row[:] for row in maze_map]

    def __getitem__(self, point):
        return self.maze_map[point.r][point.c]

    def __setitem__(self, point, value):
        self.maze_map[point.r][point.c] = value

    def solve(self, start=Point(1, 1), goal=Point(10, 10)):
        def enqueue(queue, point):
            if not self[point]:
                self[point] = 1
                queue.append(point)

        queue = []
        if start == goal:
            return start.path
        enqueue(queue, start)

        for point in queue:
            for neighbor in point.neighbors:
                if neighbor == goal:
                    return neighbor.path
                enqueue(queue, neighbor)


maze = Maze(…)
print(''.join(maze.solve()))
```

Comment: +1 for moving methods out of the `Point` class. But I still don't like the way this code uses `Point.src`. It shouldn't be the responsibility of a *point* to represent a *path*.